# using django grappelli dashboard with dotcloud

Tags: django, django-grappelli, dotcloud

I'm trying to set up admin with grappelli on dotcloud services. I've got that all up and running fine however when I try and add a custom dashboard to the equation, I get errors stating:

```
ImportError at /admin/
No module named dashboard
```

However I have installed the django-grappelli as required and it is working without dashboard. All the requisites for dashboard should be there.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli.dashboard',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

GRAPPELLI_INDEX_DASHBOARD = 'www.dashboard.CustomIndexDashboard'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little easier to solve than I first thought.

I basically just added the files for grappelli to the project rather than depending on dotcloud to install the dependencies.

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

We might need a little bit more context here. But I would first look at the following in your Django settings:

1. Check `INSTALLED_APPS` and make sure that you specify `grappelli.dashboard` and not just `dashboard`.
2. Check `GRAPPELLI_INDEX_DASHBOARD` and make sure that you specify the full path to your custom dashboard module; e.g. if the class is `MyDashboard` in the `dashboard.py` file in your `myapp` directory, it should be `myapp.dashboard.MyDashboard`.

Comment: i've added my current installed apps and the information i have within GRAPPELLI_INDEX_DASHBOARD settings.